# Changing ps4 password on a phone, will that automatically sign me out of a playstation 4 or 3 console to make me log back in with the new password?

Tags: ps4

Recently got my ps4 stolen. Credit card information is on it and i dont want the theif using my account or figuring out that he can spend my money on my account. So i changed my ps4 password using my phone. Does that automatically log me out of any console that has my account on it to relog back in with the new password? Will that stop the theif from using my account?

Comment: I would think it should, but to be double safe, you should be able to remove your credit card via the Playstation website from your account in the meantime.

Comment: I once changed a PSN password on the PS3 and was then logged out on the PS4, so it should definitely have logged you out of the console from wherever you change the password. At least it would be a major security flaw if it didn't. Maybe you should get in touch with the PS4 support in your region to see if there is anything else you should do, because if you're likely not getting the console back you should probably deactivate it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does log you out and then you have to enter the password to log in so you can rest assured the thief cant use your account if you have changed the password

Comment: He should also enable two step verification to make his account unusable without his phone.